# comando getWindow() não é reconhecido

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Alguém me ajuda pelo amor de desu, to usando SDK 29 então o problema não é esse ao menos...**

[image]

Comment: getWindow() é um método de Activity, e sua classe us AppCompatActivity, não tenho certeza se é compatível, talvez precise pegar o Activity ou fazer um cast

Comment: Tenta invalidar o cache e reiniciar. Vá em File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...> Invalidate and Restart. Chamando o método dentro da activity era pra ser possível chamar o método.

Comment: @RicardoPontual é compátivel sim.

Comment: Coloca como resposta @MurilloComino meu herói, tava com esse problema a dias estagnado sem fazer nada, esse problema tava ocorrendo com outros comandos tb e tava me torturando TE AMO PORRA

Comment: @inosivel coloquei como resposta, se puder marque ela. Que bom que ajudei! Abraços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema pode ocorrer às vezes e como você tá chamando um método que é compátivel com AppCompatActivity e não está indo, o problema pode ser no cache do android studio.

Oque você pode fazer é o seguinte:

> > > Vá em File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...> Invalidate and Restart.

Essa ação soluciona muitos problemas no Android Studio, ela é a primeira que utilizo quando tenho problemas parecidos.